# JavaScript sending post without extend libraries

Tags: javascript, forms, post, submit

I have navigation form with 4 submit buttons.

```
<form action="index.php?do=move" method="post">
<center>
<input name="north" type="submit" value="North" /><br />
<input name="west" type="submit" value="West" /><input name="east" type="submit" value="East" /><br />
<input name="south" type="submit" value="South" />
</center>
</form>
```

I need to make js function that should submit data when I pressing arrows on keyboard. 
Here is my solution but ut doesn't work :)

```
function read_key(event){
var form  = document.createElement('form');
    form.name = "arrows";
    form.method = "POST";
    form.action = "index.php?do=move";
    var sub = document.createElement('input');
    sub.type = "submit";
    if(event.keyCode==37){
        sub.name  = "west";}
    if(event.keyCode==38){
        sub.name  = "north";}
    if(event.keyCode==39){
        sub.name  = "east";}
    if(event.keyCode==40){
        sub.name  = "south";}   
    form.appendChild(sub);
    document.arrows.submit();
}
```

And connecting this to html via body onkeypress = "read_key(event)". Can somebody help me to fugure out where is mistake? I would like to relise it without extended libraries like jQuery. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: what is document.arrows?

Comment: @qqq it is the form element: document. + formname or document.forms. + formname both is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to append the form to the DOM. This should work:

```
function read_key(event){
    if(event.keyCode >=37 && event.keyCode <=40) {
    var form  = document.createElement('form');
        form.name = "arrows";
        form.method = "POST";
        form.action = "index.php?do=move";
        var sub = document.createElement('input');
        sub.type = "submit";
        if(event.keyCode==37){
            sub.name  = "west";}
        if(event.keyCode==38){
            sub.name  = "north";}
        if(event.keyCode==39){
            sub.name  = "east";}
        if(event.keyCode==40){
            sub.name  = "south";}   
        form.appendChild(sub);
        // you have to append the form to body
        document.body.appendChild(form);
        // you can do it like that:
        // document.arrows.submit();
        // but simpler is:
        form.submit();
        // remove it after submit
        document.body.removeChild(form);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But something wrong again :). I think I should try another way. Maybe it would be jQuery.

Comment: @ValeraAntonov look at the comment of  TildalWave, it is correct, your form will be generated and posted, on every key event. You'll have to check the keycode before generating. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! I'll try it and than write summary.